# Code taking too long to execute while doing batch processing of Image

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, image-processing, optimization, batch-processing

I am trying to calculate the **mean temperature** for a certain range of **zenith angle** for every image.

I am using a for loop to perform the above-mentioned task. Inside the loop, I am calculating the distance of each pixel from the center and then applying conditions based on the distance.

The image has lots of unwanted reflections, which I am removing using the **df_con** data frame.

The loop is taking 1 min 30 sec to process all the operations on one image(took 38 mins for just 24 images). Is there a way to improve the speed of the code.

```
### Reading all the images inside the Images folder
X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("Images/*.jpg"). #  Total 17,000 images of(480*640*3)
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)


X_data = [cv.imread(img) for img in files]

image_data = np.array(X_data)

T_hot = np.array([])

for r in tqdm(range(image_data[:,0,0,0].size)):

    ##Converting RGB image to grey scale image 
    grey = cv.cvtColor(image_data[r],cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    Z = grey.reshape(-1,1)

    Tem = np.array([])

    Tmax = 25 
    Tmin = -10 

    Zmax = 255 
    Zmin = 0
    c = -10

    m = (Tmax - Tmin) / (Zmax - Zmin)

    zenith = np.array([])
    theta = np.around(np.arange(0,90,90/200),6)

    for i in range(0,480):
        for j in range(0,640):

            # Calculating distance of each pixel from the center.
            r = np.around(np.sqrt((332 - j)**2 + (235 - i)**2))

            # Assigning zxenith angle to each pxl.
            # Calculating Temperature of indexed pxl.

            if r < 200:
                k = theta[theta == np.around((r*90/200),6)]
                zenith = np.append(zenith,k)
                T =  (m*grey[i,j]) + c 
                Tem = np.append(Tem,T)
            else:
                k = 120
                zenith = np.append(zenith,k) 
                T = 255
                Tem = np.append(Tem,T)



    # creating panda dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Pxl':Z[:,0],'Tem':Tem[:],'zenith':zenith[:]})

    # Fetching the Image mask data points 
    df_con = pd.read_excel('contour.xlsx')

    dataset_final = pd.merge(df,df_con, how='outer', on=None, \
                            left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=True)
    dataset_final = dataset_final[dataset_final['pxl_new'] < 255]

    df_0 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(Z.shape[0]), columns={'Null'}) 

    df_image = pd.merge(dataset_final,df_0, how='outer', on=None, \
                            left_index=True, right_index=True,\
                         sort=True)

    df_image = df_image[['Pxl','Tem','zenith']].fillna(255)


    df_target = dataset_final[(dataset_final['zenith'] >= 65) & \
                              (dataset_final['zenith'] <= 85)]
    mean = np.mean(df_target[['Tem']].values)
    T_hot = np.append(T_hot, mean)
```

Comment: Are you really loading all 17,000 images into memory all in one go to calculate their average. You normally just need one accumulator image and then add the others to it one at a time. Are you also really loading them all as colour, only to convert to greyscale? If so, you are wasting 51,000x the memory you need. Consider loading them as greyscale straight off.

Comment: Not only do you read all images in at once, you then concatenate them into one large matrix just to extract them one by one for processing. You should really consider loading them in one by one and processing them individually. Next, you should profile your code to see what operations take most time, and focus on improving those first.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am actually trying to calculate the mean temperature and plot it wrt to the timestamp of each image. That's why I loading all the images at once. 

I tried loading all the images in greyscale and yes it has significantly reduced the image loading time from 2:30sec to 0.35 sec. Also, I didn't get the accumulator image concept.

Answer (score 0):

So, after 3 long days of struggle, I managed to partially solve the problem. I noticed three things in my code:

1. I was reading all the images in color and later converting it into Grayscale which was an unnecessary extra step and causing a lot of computation time. Thanks to @Mark Setchell he pointed that out for me.

```
X_data = []

files = glob.glob ("Images/*.jpg")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)
for img in tqdm(files):
# Reading images in greyscale
    X = cv.imread(img,0);
    X_data.append(X)
```

2. I was using the panda data frame inside the loop to perform the indexing operation. Although the panda data frame makes our life easy, it takes a hell of computation time. So, I decided to go with `numpy array` instead of `panda DataFrame`.
3. I implemented multiprocessing for the below code block.

```
for i in range(0,480):
        for j in range(0,640):

            r = np.around(np.sqrt((332 - j)**2 + (235 - i)**2))

            if r < 200:
                k = theta[theta == np.around((r*90/200),6)]
                zenith = np.append(zenith,k)
                T =  (m*grey[i,j]) + c 
                Tem = np.append(Tem,T)
            else:
                k = 120
                zenith = np.append(zenith,k) 
                T = 255
                Tem = np.append(Tem,T)
```

Now the new code block is something like this:

```
def temperature(count):
    zenith = np.array([])
    Tem = np.array([])

    theta = np.around(np.arange(0, 90, 90 / 200), 6)
    for j in range(0, 640):
        r = np.around(np.sqrt((332 - j) ** 2 + (235 - count) ** 2))

        if r < 200:
            k = theta[theta == np.around((r * 90 / 200), 6)]
            zenith = np.append(zenith,k)
            T = (m * grey[count, j]) + c
            Tem = np.append(Tem,T)
        else:
            k = 120
            zenith = np.append(zenith,k)
            T = 20
            Tem = np.append(Tem,T)

    result = np.vstack((zenith, Tem)).T
    return np.array(result)
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool(cpu_count())
        result = pool.map(temperature, range(0,480))
        pool.close()
        res = np.array(result)
        Tem = res[:,:,1].reshape(-1,1)
        zenith = res[:,:,0].reshape(-1,1)
```

By implementing the above changes, I managed to reduce the processing time for single image from `1min30sec to 2sec`. I am sure there are better ways to optimize this further. Please feel free to offer your solution. It will be a big help for a fresher like me.